# php passing variables to shell command

Tags: php, html, shell

I want to pass two values from my PHP code to the shell command line. Something like this:

```
<?php
$myhost="myhost";
$mydir="mydir";
$runcommand = shell_exec("ssh $myhost du -h $mydir");
echo "<pre>$runcommand</pre>";
```

?>

I have tested different ways and no luck. If I hard code the values it works like a charm. This:

```
echo "<pre>$myhost,$mydir</pre>";
```

Shows both values being passed.

What am I missing?

Thank you for any assistance.

Wayne

Comment: much esire for debugging: `$run ="ssh $myhost du -h $mydir"; echo $run; $runcommand = shell_exec($run);`

Comment: There is no `$myhost` or `$mydir` variable in your code. When you run it goes like: `ssh du -h`. Is that a typo ?

Comment: i assumed that was typos as he OP says `echo "<pre>$myhost,$mydir</pre>";` works

Comment: I am so sorry, it was a typo. My code should showed $myhost and $mydir in the big code block.

Comment: Thank your nogad, you helped me learn a couple of new things today. Thank you for your patients with my typo.